# need help to improve efficiency of my code in R

Tags: r

I am trying to study different estimators and trying do their simulation. However, my current code is too slow, and I would like to make it more efficient. Below is the relevant excerpt:

```
covsn<-function(x,y){
    
    v=rep(0,n)
    
    for(i in 1:n)
    {
      if(n%%2==1){
        m0=floor(n/2)
      } else{
        m0=floor((n+1)/2)
      }
      
      x_other=x[-i]
      y_other=y[-i]
      
      v[i]=sort((x[i]-x_other)*(y[i]-y_other),decreasing=F)[c(m0)]
      
    }
    
    m1=floor((n+1)/2)
    
    return(sncov=sort(v)[c(m1)])
  }
  M=matrix(0,p,p)
  D=matrix(0,p,p)
  for(i in 1:p)
  {
    for(j in 1:p)
    {
      M[i,j]=covsn(X[,i],X[,j])
      
      if(i==j){
        library(robustbase)
        d=1/Sn(X[,i], constant=1.196)
        
        D[i,j]=d
      }}}
```

Comment: Certainly you don't want to be loading ``library(robustbase)`` on the inner part of a nested loop!

Comment: sure. I understand the mistake. I will change it. I want to change the for loop to apply function. But I am not getting how to do it?

Comment: The entire `if(n%%2==1)` block depends only on `n`, not on `i` and should therefore be put outside the `for` loop; also, `n` is not defined, if it is a variable defined outside the function then it should be a function argument.

Comment: Please share some example data so we can evaluate the code (and any potential suggested improvements).

Comment: Code Review is a more appropriate place to ask similar questions https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @RuiBarradas. Here n is number of sample observations, which is currently not considered as function argument.

Comment: @mhovd generated multivariate data (using mvrnorm) saved in matrix form is used

Comment: To *currently* be or not be considered hardly gives us information, is it `n<-length(x)`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas The function above is to find the robust covariance of a matrix. Thus n is the row number and p is columns of the matrix. Inside the function, I am trying to find median of median of observations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i just want to know whether i could improve the speed of my code. while profiling its showing, sorting of observations and deselection prior to sorting is causing time lag